# Perl RegistryCooker.pm is producing hash error

Tags: linux, perl, otrs

I have OTRS setup on my web server running ubuntu and I am getting this error when I try to access a separate perl application on the same system:

```
[perl:error] [pid 4649] [client IP:20534] 
Use of each() on hash after insertion without resetting hash iterator results in undefined behavior, 
Perl interpreter: 0x7f006d2d3830 at /usr/lib/perl5/ModPerl/RegistryCooker.pm line 526.
\n, referer: http://URL/otrs/index.pl?Session=100842489b87151dd7e4495da5b1b7d138
```

I don't really know what could cause this since I'm pretty new to perl. If anyone has any idea what direction I can start to investigate, it would be great.

Comment: `perl -we'%h=(a=>1,b=>2); while (each(%h)){ $h{c}=3; }'`

Comment: Ok, that does produce the same result, array out of bounds. Thing is that it references a perl module where the error occurs. I guess I need to check if the database has all the keys set

Comment: Array out of bounds??? No. No array there.

Comment: So your first step is to look for that pattern in the file and line mentioned!

Comment: The latest [`ModPerl::RegistryCooker`](https://metacpan.org/source/PHRED/mod_perl-2.0.8/ModPerl-Registry/lib/ModPerl/RegistryCooker.pm) v 2.0.8 does not appear to be using `each` around line 526.  I would therefore inspect what version you're running and if perhaps upgrading could be the best option to resolving this issue.

Comment: @ikegami, not array, but the structure used does not have the value at the key requested

Comment: @Miller That what somewhat baffled me.

Comment: Re "the structure used does not have the value at the key requested" What are you talking about?!?!?!?! The problem is inserting into a hash over which you are iterating with `each`.

Comment: Yeah, a=>1 and b=>2 exist. To my understanding the hash in perl is a key value map, and in you example your hash has a => 1 and b => 2 defined, but when you try to insert a 3 at key c, there is no key c defined in the hash, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Are your running mod_perl? If so try to disable it (for testing) and check if the error still appears. It's also possible that booth applications try to run mod_perl you need a special config.

regards

Hannes

Answer (score 0):

From the [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) page of perldoc:

> **Use of each() on hash after insertion without resetting hash iterator results in undefined behavior**
>
> (S internal) The behavior of each() after insertion is undefined, it may skip items, or visit items more than once. Consider using keys() instead of each().

I would consider changing your use of each() to use keys() instead. For example:

```
while (my ($key, $value) = each(%hash)) {
    # ...
}
```

Becomes:

```
for my $key (keys %hash) {
    my $value = $hash{$key};
    # ...
}
```

That way the keys you are looping around is set to a fixed value just before the first time around the loop, and no undefined behavior can occur.